# Node method to resolve a simple circuit, I’m stuck here

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

So keep in mind that I’m a beginner, this is a secondary exam in my university and i just started with exercises so be kind with me :)

[image: Here is the circuit]

[image: Here is the “obscure” step]

I can’t figure out what happened in that step.
It seems like they used some parallel resistor transformation but really don’t know how.

Comment: It is math: they make a common denominator (the denominator is the number under the 'division bar')

Comment: Yeah now i understood, but the inverse of the Rvet is very similar to the formula in the parallel resistor transformation so i messed up. Thanks for saying what a denominator is, Oldfart. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [Norton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_theorem)!

BTW: The question seems to have an fault, since J_2 is given, but not  shown in the circuit diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO7coE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's much easier!

**Regarding your step**

The matrix is

$$ \mathbf{Y} \cdot \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{J}\, .$$

To get **V**, you have to invert the **Y** matrix:

$$   \mathbf{Y}^{-1} \mathbf{Y} \cdot \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{Y}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \\
\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{Y}^{-1} \mathbf{J} \, . $$

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it inverses the matrix here. You can try to inverse the matrix based on the [equation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have Rmat.Vvec = Jvec.

What they've done is pre-multiply both sides by the inverse of Rmat, to get Rmat_inv.Rmat.Vvec = Rmat_inv.Jvec, which simplifies (as a matrix times its inverse is unity) to Vvec = Rmat_inv.Jvec.

The exciting things happening to the R terms are the result of taking the matrix inverse.